# how to define a structure in ARM assembly language using as assembler?

Tags: assembly, struct, arm, gnu-assembler

Using an **x86** processor and **NASM** compiler I could define a structure like this:

```
section .bss
 STRUCT my_structure
   elem_1: RESW 1
   elem_2: RESW 1
   elem_3: RESD 1
 ENDSTRUC
```

I could then use it like:

```
section .data
 s: ISTRUC my_structure
   AT elem_1, DW 0x01
   AT elem_2, DW 0x02
   AT elem_3, DD 0x0
 IEND
```

How could I do the same in an **ARM** processor using **as** assembler ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67614824/471129

Comment: have you tested it?

Comment: No, I'm just the messenger on this one; why do you ask if I've tested it?  That answer comes from a highly respected colleague, though, so maybe, try it for yourself?

Comment: I tested it, but don't work using as compiler though

Comment: @ginko: Please show the exact code you tried, the command you ran, and the behavior you observed.  Also the version of the assembler you are using (there are several different assemblers that call the command `as`, including the GNU assembler and clang). The `.struct` code in the second code block of [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614570/struct-directive-of-gnu-assembler-how-to-instantiate-a-class-instance/67614824#67614824) assembles without errors for me, using GNU as 2.39.